# Smiled out of acceptance and happiness

Tags: fatwa

While I was listening to dikr for the night and one dikr came on and it was saying that "I accept that Allah is God and Mohammed (pbuh) is his messanger and Islam as a religion" and when I heard it as I was saying it I smiled because I like this dikr because it's so pure and I was smiling because it brings me joy but then I got scared thinking that maybe because I smiled that was me as if I'm mocking Islam and Allah (swt)

Comment: Thank you so much jazakaallah Kahir. May Allah grant you Jannah al Firdous and make your life easy and your hereafter easy and make you one of the close ones. May Allah grant you your wishes that are good for you and keep everything bad away from you and protect you from everything evil and may the merciful have mercy on you and strengthen your iman. Ameen. Peace my brother and thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allah can read your intentions, so do not worry about what you did may seem like.

> “People will be resurrected (and judged) according to their intentions.” ([Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1293320))

If you had the right intentions Allah knows it and he will reward you for it. Allah will never get confused about your actions.